# How to dual boot (Ubuntu-Win) with Lenovo U41-70? - Issue with partitions and recovery

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot, lenovo-laptop

My Lenovo U41-70 (i7-5500U) came with a licensed Windows 8.1 (upgradable to Windows 10) and has by default the following partitions:

1. ~1000 MB (Recovery partition)
2. ~260 MB (EFI system partition)
3. ~1000 MB (OEM partition)
4. ~13 GB (recovery partition)
5. ~25 GB (Primary partition) - D: drive called Lenovo to store data
6. ~900 GB (boot, page file, crash dump, primary partition) - C: with the OS installed

It has a recovery button/software which allows you to recover the original OS, namely the Windows 8.1 but I didn't get any Windows installation disk. The problem is that this recovery software seems to work only if the original partitions are untouched. Therefore if I create a partition for Ubuntu or for keeping my data separated from the OS I will lose my licensed Windows.

My question is: how can I install Ubuntu and create 1 or 2 data partitions without losing the possibility to reinstall my (licensed) Windows?

The recovery software installs back Windows 8.1 but I actually use Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this step:

-Buy a usb or cd.

-Download rufus or win32 disk imager for ready your usb from ISO.

-Ready your USB.

-Put the usb in the pc.

-Join in the bios and boot menu.

-Select the usb or pc and press enter.

-Install Ubuntu with graphic installer and select "ubuntu with windows"

-Restart the pc.

Comment: Either I don't understand the answer or you didn't understand the question. Do these steps install Ubuntu in the same partition than Windows?? Doesn't the format of the partition need to be different any more? In any case, this does not solve the problem to create 1 or 2 separated partitions for data.